# Amazon EC2 access denied

Tags: amazon-ec2

I had a credit card problem and delayed payment of my EC2 instance. I already paid, but eventhough my instance is running, I can't access it, not using an ftp app (filezilla) nor using SSH client...I get a "Connection reset by Peer" error message

Does this has to do with the payment issue? (I paid less than 24 hours ago)

thanks!!

Comment: Can you clarify what you tried and what you want?

Comment: Thanks @Meeesh ...I want to know if Amazon takes too much time to re-allow you to access your instance after a payment issue

Comment: If the instance is running, then it would have nothing to do with a payment issue. Search for standard advice about connecting to an EC2 instance (eg security groups), or provide more information here about your configuration and how you are trying to connect.

Comment: IF the instance is running :)

Comment: Like John said, if it is running, it should be working fine. What have you tried to do to connect. You might not be accessing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you wouldn't get a "Connection reset by Peer" error as a result of a delayed payment. 
If any actions were going to be performed to your resources as a result of non payment (eg. termination), you would receive an email notifying you about it along with a time window for you to make the payment.